# 400 Bad Request when posting JSON data to PHP page using socket

Tags: php, python, json, sockets, post

I'm trying to write a program which reads in temperature and humidity values from a Pysense device and stores the values in a database, which is hosted on my laptop. To do so, I am using a socket to send Json data via POST to a php page, which then decodes the Json data and inserts the appropriate values into the database. The problem I am having is that I am receiving a '400 bad request' response when trying to send the data to the php page. I assume this is something to do with the formatting of my Json data but I cannot find any solution online which works for me. Here is my code below:

Here, the hum and temp values are the readings from the device.

```
data = '{ "DeviceName": 1, "Humidity": %.2f, "Temperature": %.2f }'%(hum,temp)

header = ("""
POST /insert.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.2
Content-Type: application/json\r\n
""")

contentLengthStr = 'Content-Length : %s\r\n\r\n'%str(len(data))
request = header + contentLengthStr + data
print(request)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
s.send(request.encode())
response = s.recv(4096)
print(response)
```

I'd expect the data to be decoded by the php page but here is the response I  am getting from the console:

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nDate: Tue, 29 Jan 2019 16:12:06 GMT\r\nServer: Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0h PHP/7.2.6\r\nVary: accept-language,accept-charset\r\nAccept-Ranges: bytes\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Language: en\r\nExpires: Tue, 29 Jan 2019 16:12:06 GMT\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nBad request!\r\n\r\n*/-->\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nBad request!'

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you're using such a low-level method to send this data?  Many people prefer to use a higher-level package such as `requests` or `httplib`.

Comment: I second @JohnGordon 's comment. I'd very much recommend you look at the `requests` module.

Comment: In addition, are you reading the information directly from the device? Without a more complete code example? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question to include something a bit more complete?

Comment: Without more information regarding how the device is queried, and what database and database schema you're dealing with, I'd guess that you could do all this using the `requests`, `json` (look at `json.dumps()` for that module) and `sqlite` modules in one very simple, short script.

Answer (score 0):

```
header = ("""
POST /insert.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.2
Content-Type: application/json\r\n
""")
```

Triple-quoted strings retain all the information inside them, including the newlines at the beginning and end.  So, when you join this together with the content-length string and the data, your request ends up looking like this:

```
POST /insert.php HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.2
Content-Type: application/json

Content-Length : 59

{ "DeviceName": 1, ... }
```

The extra blank line between `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` is a problem.  The one at the beginning might be also, but I'm not sure about that.

Using a library such as `requests` would prevent this sort of silly mistake.